# Manager isn't accessible via Account instances

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-organizations

In using django-organizations to give my project organizations, I made a separate app for accounts.

Using the code from the docs (https://django-organizations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#advanced-customization-using-abstract-models) in what I assume is a basic case, I am trying to add them on

the `admin.py` page:

```
from accounts import models as AccountModels

@admin.register(AccountModels.Account)
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['slug', 'active', ]
```

This gives an error when trying to view the list on admin page for Accounts (at `http://localhost:8000/adminaccounts/account/`) [ps - the `add` page renders, but will provide the same error on save]:

> AttributeError at /adminaccounts/account/
>
> Manager isn't accessible via Account instances

Looking at the error, I am not supposed to be calling it on an instance, rather only a Class.   But the default admin template is rendering this page, so I am wary of editing that.  Is there something I am missing related to setting up an inherited class in an admin class?  (the organization-user and organization-owner both display properly adding to my confusion)

This is the stack that shows that it is trying to access an instance (but I can't find in the stack trace which line is the producing the error, only that it is in the `{{content}}` part of the template block):

```
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myFirst/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py in lookup_field
            attr = getattr(obj, name) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable      Value
model_admin   <accounts.admin.AccountAdmin object at 0x11e0185f8>
name          'active'
obj           <Account: Funny Clowns With Paper Boats>
opts          <Options for Account>

/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myFirst/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in __get__
            raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable      Value
cls           <class 'accounts.models.Account'>
instance      <Account: Funny Clowns With Paper Boats>
self          <django.db.models.manager.ManagerDescriptor object at 0x11dabb978>
```

The accounts `models.py` (just the same as the docs):

```
from django.db import models
from organizations.abstract import (AbstractOrganization,
                                    AbstractOrganizationUser,
                                    AbstractOrganizationOwner)

class Account(AbstractOrganization):
    monthly_subscription = models.IntegerField(default=1000)

class AccountUser(AbstractOrganizationUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='')

class AccountOwner(AbstractOrganizationOwner):
    pass
```

I do not have any functional views or Class based views in the `accounts` app, so I don't know if I am supposed to override a manager or search query or view...

Trying to override the view(?) of the admin :

```
@admin.register(Account)
class AccountAdmin(BaseOrganizationAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(AccountAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        print(Account)         # <class 'accounts.models.Account'>
        print(type(Account))   # <class 'organizations.base.OrgMeta'>
        print(type(qs))        # <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
        return qs # or Account
```

This either produces the previous error, or `type object 'Account' has no attribute 'filter'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have:

`list_display = ['slug', 'active', ]`

But `active` refers to the `ActiveManager` instance. You want `is_active`, which refers to the model field.